# PHP Date function for Monday through Thursday only

Tags: php, date

I have a delivery service that only picks up Monday through Thursday.  I only want to give the user the next available three days as an option for a scheduled pickup.

My code works, but I was wondering if there was a more "efficient" way to write what Im trying to achieve?

```
$numericDay=date('N');
        if ($numericDay==1) {
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 days')) . '">' . date('\T\o\m\o\r\r\o\w - F j, Y', strtotime('+1 days')) . '</option>';
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+2 days')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('+2 days')) . '</option>';
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+3 days')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('+3 days')) . '</option>';
        }
        if ($numericDay==2) {
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 days')) . '">' . date('\T\o\m\o\r\r\o\w - F j, Y', strtotime('+1 days')) . '</option>';
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+2 days')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('+2 days')) . '</option>';
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('next monday')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next monday')) . '</option>';
        }
        if ($numericDay==3) {           
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 days')) . '">' . date('\T\o\m\o\r\r\o\w - F j, Y', strtotime('+1 days')) . '</option>';
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+next monday')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next monday')) . '</option>';
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('next tuesday')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next tuesday')) . '</option>';
        }
        if ($numericDay>=4 and $numericDay<=7) {
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('next monday')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next monday')) . '</option>';
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('next tuesday')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next tuesday')) . '</option>';
            echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('next wednesday')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next wednesday')) . '</option>';
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!!!

Comment: What's not efficient? If you just want a code review, you should go to  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ SO is more for when you can't solve a problem

Comment: If nothing else, you could cut the number of strtotime() calls in HALF by simply caching the values in a variable before building your strings.

Comment: Here must posted problems not rewiews how `Marc B` said!

Comment: Also, a `switch` looks much better :) .

Comment: @Juan Mendes Im still relatively new to stack overflow, I understand this question was more of a discussion question than asking to solve a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need ...

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$x = 0;
while ( $x < 3 ) {
    $dateTime->modify("+1 day");
    if ($dateTime->format("N") > 4)
        continue;
    printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>\n", $dateTime->format("Ymd"), $dateTime->format("l - F j, Y"));
    $x ++;
}
```

Output

```
<option value="20130225">Monday - February 25, 2013</option>
<option value="20130226">Tuesday - February 26, 2013</option>
<option value="20130227">Wednesday - February 27, 2013</option>
```

Comment: Thanks, I's give this a try!

Comment: Modified it to print out the option

Comment: @Baba can you explain this "\"%s\">%s</option>\n" ?

Comment: It used for printing formatted strings ... Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

Comment: That doesn't work. At least not for me. If I run the above code, I get saturday, sunday and monday. It should be monday, tuesday and wednesday. OP only wants the next three days that are monday through thursday.

Comment: Typo ... it should be `$dateTime->format("N") > 4` not `$dateTime->format("N") < 4` .. fixed

Comment: @Baba I getting the same response as Rickard.

Comment: @Adam see updated code .... see example can you see it shows Wednesday  ,  Thursday and Monday ???

Comment: @Baba Sorry I posted the comment and then saw your update. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do.

```
$offsets = array(
    1 => array(1, 2, 3),
    2 => array(1, 2, 6),
    3 => array(1, 5, 6),
    4 => array(4, 5, 6),
    5 => array(3, 4, 5),
    6 => array(2, 3, 4),
    7 => array(1, 2, 3)
);

$numericDay = date('N');
foreach ($offsets[$numericDay] as $offset)
{
    $dateFormat = $offset == 1 ? '\T\o\m\o\r\r\o\w - F j, Y' : 'l - F j, Y';
    echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+' . $offset . ' days')) . '">' . date($dateFormat, strtotime('+' . $offset . ' days')) . '</option>';
}
```

Edit: Tidied it up a bit.

Comment: Best answer, better then mine

Comment: @Rickard Thank you, this works really well!  I did not think of using an array of arrays!

Comment: @Rickard Andersson Are you getting the "Tomorrow" to echo?

Comment: Yeah, it works for me. If the offset is 1, it uses the tomorrow date format. You have to fast-forward todays date to sunday in order to test it though.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a while loop:**

```
$echoedDays = 0;
$dateIndex = 0
while ($echoedDays < 3) {
```

Start from tomorrow's date and check the day number. If it's Mon-Thu (1-4), echo the date and increase `$echoedDays`. Otherwise just increase `$dateIndex` and move to the next date.

Answer (score 0):

This could also work:

```
 $numericDay=date('N');

    if($numericDay < 4)
        echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 days')) . '">' . date('\T\o\m\o\r\r\o\w - F j, Y', strtotime('+1 days')) . '</option>';
    else
        echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('next monday')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next monday')) . '</option>';

    if($numericDay < 3)
        echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+2 days')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('+2 days')) . '</option>';
    else
        echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('next tuesday')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next tuesday')) . '</option>';

    if($numericDay < 2)
        echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('+3 days')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('+3 days')) . '</option>';
    else
        echo '<option value="' . date('Ymd', strtotime('next wednesday')) . '">' . date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next wednesday')) . '</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mod 4 is your friend...

```
$days = Array("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun");

for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){
  if($i > 4){ $n = 1; } else {
    $n = $i%4+1;
  }
  $o = ($n)%4+1;
  $p = ($o)%4+1;
  echo "It's ".$days[$i-1]." and the next three available days are... ".$days[$n-1].", ".$days[$o-1]." and ".$days[$p-1]."\n";
}
```

### Output

```
It's Mon and the next three available days are... Tue, Wed and Thu
It's Tue and the next three available days are... Wed, Thu and Mon
It's Wed and the next three available days are... Thu, Mon and Tue
It's Thu and the next three available days are... Mon, Tue and Wed
It's Fri and the next three available days are... Mon, Tue and Wed
It's Sat and the next three available days are... Mon, Tue and Wed
It's Sun and the next three available days are... Mon, Tue and Wed
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$store = array(
    1 => array(
        date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 days')),
        date('\T\o\m\o\r\r\o\w - F j, Y', strtotime('+1 days'))
    ),
    array(
        date('Ymd', strtotime('+2 days')),
        date('\T\o\m\o\r\r\o\w - F j, Y', strtotime('+2 days'))
    ),
    array(
        date('Ymd', strtotime('+3 days')),
        date('\T\o\m\o\r\r\o\w - F j, Y', strtotime('+3 days'))
    ),
    'm' => array(
        date('Ymd', strtotime('next monday')),
        date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next monday'))
    ),
    't' => array(
        date('Ymd', strtotime('next tuesday')),
        date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next tuesday'))
    ),
    'w' => array(
        date('Ymd', strtotime('next wednesday')),
        date('l - F j, Y', strtotime('next wednesday'))
    )
);

$numericDay=date('N');
if ($numericDay==1) {
    echo '<option value="' . $store[1][0] . '">' . $store[1][1] . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="' . $store[2][0] . '">' . $store[2][1] . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="' . $store[3][0] . '">' . $store[3][1] . '</option>';
}
elseif ($numericDay==2) {
    echo '<option value="' . $store[1][0] . '">' . $store[1][1] . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="' . $store[2][0] . '">' . $store[2][1] . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="' . $store['m'][0] . '">' . $store['m'][1] . '</option>';
}
elseif ($numericDay==3) {           
    echo '<option value="' . $store[1][0] . '">' . $store[1][1] . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="' . $store['m'][0] . '">' . $store['m'][1] . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="' . $store['t'][0] . '">' . $store['t'][1] . '</option>';
}
elseif ($numericDay>=4 and $numericDay<=7) {
    echo '<option value="' . $store[1][0] . '">' . $store[1][1] . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="' . $store['t'][0] . '">' . $store['t'][1] . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="' . $store['w'][0] . '">' . $store['w'][1] . '</option>';
}
```